# como modificar mi perfil segun el Id de un usuario En laravel + Vue

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

Hola soy nuevo en laravel Y tengo un problema a la hora de obtener los datos según cada Cuenta. no se como enviarle el Id único de mi cuenta a  a Vue+axios par que axios muestre automáticamente mi información según la cuenta

(la carga de la información funciona bien pero solo si es estático, En este ej. le puse el 2,etc. Y carga bien)

```html
var url = 'conf/2' // le he pasado el 2 de manera estatica
```

una pequeña parte de mi codigo

```html
getPerfil:function(){
   var url = 'conf/2';
   axios.get(url).then(response=>{
    this.info = response.data
   });
  },
```

Y bien hasta ahí todo perfecto me carga la información pero no de manera dinamica según cada Cuenta.

---

otro problema que tengo me he dado he percatado es de que puedo modificar cualquier cuenta  solo con cambiar el ID. lo cual
Si esto  es un problema de seguridad porque cualquiera podría  insertar información en x cuenta.

Comment: no estaria entendiendo tu problema. Si estas en VUE, cual es el problema de sumarle al string una variable?

Comment: @gbianchi no es  ninguna problema  sumarle un string a una variable. el problema es como obtener   el ID de forma dinamica segun X cuenta(logeada)  en laravel.

Comment: Ok. por lo que vos mostraste aca, que es codigo en VUE (en realidad js, pero bueno), no se entiende entonces donde teens el problema. Porque si fuera VUE, seguro tendrias el usuario en alguna variable y podrias pasar ese ID a axios para que haga la consulta. Podras aclarar done esta exactamente el problema entonces?

Comment: @gbianchi bueno si tienes razón es que solo inserte una pequeña parte de lo que era mi problema, no tengo el usuario en ninguna variable  eso es lo que quiero saber. como podria obtener el ID de mi cuenta para poder pasarsela a Axios y cargue la información.

Comment: y volvemos a la pregunta inicial. donde esta el usuario? en alguna parte esta..

Comment: @gbianchi en laravel cuando imprimo mi Id  lo hago de esta forma 
{{ auth()->user()->id    para hacer otras cosas. pero no sé como le envio ese ID a vue para que axios cargue mi información.

Comment: Por ahi va tu pregunta... eso es lo que tendria que decir la pregunta.. ademas de la parte de VUE.. por favor, tomate un segundo para describir ese problema, mostrar en que controlador esta tu usuario, como la cargo tu programa y esas cosas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumiendo que el usuario ya ha iniciado sesión, y que es el usuario actual, podrías usar el facade Auth o el helper auth() para obtener el id del usuario:

```
getPerfil:function(){
        var url = 'conf/' + '{{auth()->user()->id}}';
        axios.get(url).then(response=>{
            this.info = response.data
        });
    },
```